# Bizarre math error when doing a basic check in C

Tags: c

For a simple program, the assignment was to create a program that accepts a ten digit phone number, and then reads it back to the user.
There were to be controls to ensure that:

1. The first digit is not 0.
2. That the number entered is ten numbers.

The error check seemed simple; I thought using a while loop to ensure that the range of the number was between 1000000000 and 9999999999 would work out, and according to independent calculations, it seems it should.

```
while ((MDN - valueCheck < 0) || (MDN > 9999999999)) {
  printf("Entered number is not ten digits. Please re-enter.\n");
  scanf("%d", &MDN);
}
```

Both `MDN` and `valueCheck` are `long long` type variables (so that the range can go past 2,147,483,647; IIRC long long was 64-bit), but they seem to still be listed as 32-bit integers, as entering `2147483647` comes out just fine (or any lower phone number works as well), but entering 2,147,483,648 (or anything above) causes it to be displayed as `-2147483647`.

Related to the above, entering a higher number, not only does the value wrap around the range of the 32-bit integer, but the phone number printed by the `printf` statement after the loop is always equal to the entered number minus twice the limit of a 32-bit integer.

Is there any simple way to make the program actually work in 64-bit numbers like I wanted it to? The algorithm seems solid, if I can make the math work properly.

Comment: How are the variables MDN and valueCheck being populated?

Comment: Why not read the phone number into a char array?

Comment: "%d" in scanf scans a 64 bit integer? I would think it's something like "%lld". How are MDN and valueCheck declared?

Answer (score 5):

Try `scanf("%lld", &MDN);` instead of `scanf("%d", &MDN);`

From man scanf:

```
ll (ell ell)
              Indicates that the conversion will be one of dioux or n and the
              next pointer is a pointer to a long long int (rather than int).
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there any simple way to make the program actually work in 64-bit numbers like I wanted it to?
A: Use `int64_t` and `"%" SCNx64`.

If you:
want 32-bit integers, use type `int32_t`.
want 64-bit integers, use type `int64_t`.
use `int`, the range is at *least* `-32767` to `+32767`.
use `long`, the range is at *least* `-2147483647` to `+2147483647`.
use `long long`, the range is at *least* `-9223372036854775807` to `+9223372036854775807`.

With `scanf()` use the matching format specifier:

```
int               "%d"  
long              "%ld"  
long long         "%lld"  
int32_t           "%" SCNx32  
int64_t           "%" SCNx64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could've used this:

```
scanf("%lld", &MDN);
```

but there are issues with *coding* and *approach* itself (see below)
I would advise to stick to string-regexp input-validation approach instead.
**Coding issue**:
scanf() in a loop is vulnerable to *unprocessed-input-buffer issue*, e.g if user enters a text instead of a number - scanf() will fail, stdin won't be consumed and loop will continue eternally.

See "[How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)" for details. Following change should address it:

```
while(!scanf("%lld", &MDN)) {
    char c;
    while(c=getchar()!='\n'&& c!=EOF);
}
```

**Approach issue:**

The approach itself is vulnerable to overflow and type-trimming issues.
For example: "-9999999999999999999" will pass all MDN validations (see below).

Also there could be compiler/specific issues while comparing long long (MDN)
to an integer (0 or 9999999999 instead of 0LL or 9999999999LL).

```
Entered number is not ten digits. Please re-enter.
-9999999999999999999
"MDN" is -9223372036854775808
"MDN > 9999999999" is false
"MDN - valueCheck < 0" is false (!) because "MDN - valueCheck" is 9223372035854775808
```

Comment: %ld will scan a long int. OP has a long long int.

Comment: Agree - "%ld" will truncate it under 32-bit envs - my bad. Will update the answer with this and more interesting issues shortly.